# Creating "flippable" content in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm currently trying to build my personal website with Silverlight 3 and I've got this idea that you should be able to flip through the content in a certain way. I haven't seen exactly what I wanted before, so I uploaded a screenshot of the design for you guys to get a better idea of what I'm talking about:

[Picture of desired effect http://www.bo-mortensen.dk/bmdkflip.jpg](http://www.bo-mortensen.dk/bmdkflip.jpg)

As you can see it's more or less a carousel on the X axis. I've seen a fair number of carousel tutorials, but it seems to be quite "complicated" for what I'm looking for.

My main problem is that I fail to understand how to make this thing dynamic. I can sure do the flipping animations, but when it comes to the best approach of making the bottom page (the mirrored one) the previous etc, I'm a bit lost :)

I'm looking for any good advice on how to make this dynamic in such a way that the only thing that needs to be changed is the content itself (text, pictures etc) Also, I believe that each page/usercontrol should be using the same two (flip up and flip down) animations, if that's possible at all?

Hope I made myself clear on this - it's late after all ;) If not, just let me know and I'll see if I can elaborate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for a Flippable 3D control. So check out my blog for one and you can tweak it to make vertical rotation.

http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2009/04/3d-flipper-control-using-silverlight-30.html

Comment: Jobi, that's perfect!! Thanks a lot :) greatly appreciated.

Just had to modify it so it uses UserControls instead of UIElement and tweak the animation. Good stuff!